# Core data - entity not returning saved data swift

Tags: swift, database, core-data

I'm trying to save and load data to and from core data.

this is my struct

```
struct QuizContact {
    var id: String?
    var status: String?
    var app_installed: Bool?
    var contact_no: String?
    var picture: String?
    var connect_type: String?
    var name: String?
}

extension QuizContact: Codable {
    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) throws {
        self = try JSONDecoder().decode(QuizContact.self, from: JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary))
    }
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name, app_installed, status, contact_no, picture, connect_type
    }
}
```

this is my db handler class

```
class DatabaseHandler {
    
    private init() { }
    
    // MARK: Shared Instance
    
    static let shared = DatabaseHandler()
    
    // MARK: Local Variable
    
    var managedObjectContext : NSManagedObjectContext? = {
        if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
            return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }()
    
    func saveContactsToDB(contact: QuizContact) {
        if let managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext {
            
            var isUserContactSaved = false
            
            if let id = contact.id {
                let userConatctsFromDB = fetchSavedUserContatcsVideos(id: id)
                
                if userConatctsFromDB.isEmpty {
                    isUserContactSaved = true
                }
            }
            
            if !isUserContactSaved {
                let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "UserContactInDB", in: managedObjectContext)!
                let contactMO = UserContactInDB(entity: entity, insertInto: managedObjectContext)
                contactMO.name = contact.name
                contactMO.contact_no = contact.contact_no
                contactMO.id = contact.id
                contactMO.status = contact.status
                contactMO.app_installed = contact.app_installed ?? false
            }
            
            do {
              try managedObjectContext.save()
                print("Saved to database \(contact.name ?? "") \(contact.contact_no ?? "")")
            } catch {
                print("Could not save to database \(contact.name ?? "") \(contact.contact_no ?? ""). Error:  \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func fetchSavedUserContatcsVideos(id: String) -> [UserContactInDB] {
        return fetchUserContactsFromDB(predicate: NSPredicate(format: "id contains[c] %@ ", id))
    }
    
    func fetchUserContactsFromDB(predicate: NSPredicate? = nil) -> [UserContactInDB] {
        if let managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext {
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<UserContactInDB>(entityName: "UserContactInDB")

            if let predicate = predicate {
                fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
            }
            
            do {
              return try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            } catch {
              print("Could not fetch. \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        return []
    }
}
```

The print statement for saving the contact is working. I do see print results.

But when I fetch using `let contactsFromDB = DatabaseHandler.shared.fetchUserContactsFromDB(predicate: nil)` it always gives empty array.

I tried adding breakpoint at `return try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)`, the `fetchRequest` printed `NSFetchRequest<UserContactInDB> = <extracting data from value failed>`

Could anybody guide me what is the problem?

Comment: If `isUserContactSaved` is true nothing will be saved but the print statement you mention will still be executed, maybe you should double check this. And maybe you should refactor this part so the flow through this function gets more straight forward

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks for pointing out... i see my mistake